# How to Open Android App After a 10-Second Long Press Even When the App is Not in the Background

Tags: javascript, java, android, react-native

I've created a module file VolumeManager.java

```
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.os.Handler;
import android.os.Looper;
import android.view.KeyEvent;

public class VolumeButtonReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private static final int LONG_PRESS_DURATION = 10000; // 10 seconds
    private boolean volumeUpPressed = false;
    private Handler handler = new Handler(Looper.getMainLooper());

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (event != null && event.getKeyCode() == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_VOLUME_UP) {
                int action = event.getAction();
                if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_DOWN) {
                    volumeUpPressed = true;
                    handler.postDelayed(() -> {
                        if (volumeUpPressed) {
                            // Volume up button was held for 10 seconds
                            // Perform the API call here
                            performApiCall(context);
                        }
                        volumeUpPressed = false;
                    }, LONG_PRESS_DURATION);
                } else if (action == KeyEvent.ACTION_UP) {
                    // Volume up button was released
                    volumeUpPressed = false;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    private void performApiCall(Context context) {
        // Implement the logic to make an API call here
        // You can use AsyncTask or any other approach to perform the API call
        // Replace this with your API call logic
    }
}
```

to handle long presses of the volume button and open my Android app, even if it's not in the background. Once the app is opened, I also want to perform additional actions. Can someone review my code and help me understand if I've made any mistakes in the implementation or if this approach is feasible? Additionally, how should I configure my AndroidManifest.xml file for this functionality

```
<receiver
    android:name=".VolumeButtonReceiver"
    android:enabled="true"
    android:exported="true">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>
```

Comment: the only way for achieving this is to implement `AccessibilityService` and it will be working only when device is on and unlocked